# Is it possible to not "bind" the $index when interpolating?

Tags: angularjs

I have an ng-repeat list and I'm trying to alternate background colors for each item by doing

```
class="bg-{{$index%3}}"
```

but its also binding to $index despite changing the order of items resulting in items having a strict background color order of color 1, color2, color 3, so on. I want it to be such that the bg colors/class do not change when order is changed. Each item should have the class assigned only once.

Demo of problem: [plunker](http://plnkr.co/edit/89a9Jfmnni5YEgCRkpH9?p=preview)

Comment: Would it be okay to have a callback when the items are fetched, and set the color then? Then you would be able to bind to `{{item.color}}` instead.

Comment: Btw, you should initialize your list of assignments in your controller, not with ng-init. There's a note about this in the docs; [AngularJS: API: ngInit](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/directive/ngInit).

Comment: Would prefer not to decorate data also updated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

i think this is what you are looking for, note ng-init assigns firs time index to the item. Just to be sure I also added to orderBy name but it does not related to the solution.

```
<h1 style="background: #333">Click the switch on the right side to toggle</h1>
<div ng-repeat="assignment in assignments  | orderBy:['isPutOff', 'name']" ng-init="assignment.index = assignment.index||$index">
```

http://plnkr.co/edit/3t5G32akJay7NJ9dxe2U?p=preview

Answer (score 0):

Yes , You need to do it like this

```
<div ng-repeat="assignment in assignments track by $index | orderBy:'isPutOff'">
  <section class="{{'bg-'+($index%3)}}" ng-class="{'bg-grey':assignment.isPutOff}">
........
```

Comment: its breaking the orderBy clause. grey ones should be ordered to the bottom.